# How to create new instance of a Q_GADGET struct in QML?

Tags: c++, qt, struct, qml, signals-slots

I can emit signals with structs tagged with Q_GADGET from C++ to QML.

Is it possible send such a struct from QML to a C++ slot? My code fails on the first step: creating an instance in QML.

This code fails on the first line ...

```
var bs = new BatteryState()
bs.percentRemaining = 1.0
bs.chargeDate = new Date()
DataProvider.setBatteryState(bs)
```

... with error:

```
qrc:///main.qml:34: ReferenceError: BatteryState is not defined
```

I can emit a BatteryStatus struct from C++ to QML, but I would like to send one back as a single parameter to a slot.

Here is BatteryState.h & BatteryState.cpp:

```
// BatteryState.h
#pragma once

#include <QDate>
#include <QMetaType>

struct BatteryState
{
    Q_GADGET
    Q_PROPERTY(float percentRemaining  MEMBER percentRemaining)
    Q_PROPERTY(QDate date              MEMBER date)

public:
    explicit BatteryState();
    BatteryState(const BatteryState& other);
    virtual ~BatteryState();
    BatteryState& operator=(const BatteryState& other);
    bool operator!=(const BatteryState& other) const;
    bool operator==(const BatteryState& other) const;

    float percentRemaining;
    QDate date;
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(BatteryState)

// BatteryState.cpp
#include "BatteryState.h"

BatteryState::BatteryState()
    : percentRemaining(), date(QDate::currentDate())
{}

BatteryState::BatteryState(const BatteryState& other)
    : percentRemaining(other.percentRemaining),
      date(other.date)
{}

BatteryState::~BatteryState() {}

BatteryState&BatteryState::operator=(const BatteryState& other)
{
    percentRemaining = other.percentRemaining;
    date = other.date;
    return *this;
}

bool BatteryState::operator!=(const BatteryState& other) const {
    return (percentRemaining != other.percentRemaining
            || date != other.date);
}

bool BatteryState::operator==(const BatteryState& other) const {
    return !(*this != other);
}
```

I register this type in main.cpp:

```
qRegisterMetaType<BatteryState>();
```

Recommendations?

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-definetypes.html#registering-an-instantiable-object-type ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't create `Q_GADGET`s in QML, QML objects need to be `QObject` derived, and are **not** created via `new` - that's for JS objects only. Gadgets just generate meta data so that you can access their members and such from QML and pass around, that's about it.

> Is it possible send such a struct from QML to a C++ slot?

It is possible to send, but it would not be created in QML. It could be returned to QML from a C++ function or be exposed as a property of some object.

```
struct Test {
    Q_GADGET
    Q_PROPERTY(int test MEMBER test)
  public:
    Test() : test(qrand()) {}
    int test;
    Q_SLOT void foo() { qDebug() << "foo"; }
};

class F : public QObject { // factory exposed as context property F
    Q_OBJECT
  public slots:
    Test create() { return Test(); }
    void use(Test t) { qDebug() << t.test; }
};


    // from QML
    property var tt: F.create()

    Component.onCompleted: {
      F.use(F.create()) // works
      var t = F.create()
      console.log(t.test) // works
      F.use(t) // works
      console.log(tt.test) // works
      F.use(tt) // works
      tt.test = 555
      F.use(tt) // works
      t.test = 666
      F.use(t) // works
      t.foo() // works
    }
```

Comment: I have a question. I tried a lot of way to auto completation on this way but I have no success. example if i typed t. +(ctrl+space) there is no option of struct members. How can do this?

Comment: I doubt there is anything you can do at the moment. Hopefully in time Creator will get better at providing auto completion in QML.

Comment: this results `unknown type` error. you need to declare it using `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE()` and register it using `qRegisterMetaType<>()`. [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67961995/1074799)

Comment: You can create Q_GADGETS in QML using a C++ factory object registered to be accessible in QML, and a Q_INVOKABLE function in this factory which returns an instance of the Q_GADGET object. The object it returns should also be a member of the factory class. This object can then be passed from QML to C++ via Q_INVOKABLE functions. You can even store a Q_GADGET object as a QML property using the following syntax: property var my_property: my_factory.makeQGadgetObject()