# Best way to access a cpp structure in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick, qvariant

I need to pass structures between cpp and QML. If i use **property** i should create an individual set and get functions, My structure contains minimum 5 members so i felt it's not good to use set and get for all those members.
Following is an example of what i am trying to do :

**MyClass.h**

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>
using namespace std;

struct MyStruct {
Q_GADGET
int m_val;
QString m_name1;
QString m_name2;
QString m_name3;
QString m_name4;
Q_PROPERTY(int val MEMBER m_val)
Q_PROPERTY(QString name1 MEMBER m_name1)
Q_PROPERTY(QString name2 MEMBER m_name2)
Q_PROPERTY(QString name3 MEMBER m_name3)
Q_PROPERTY(QString name4 MEMBER m_name4)
};

class MyClass:public QObject
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(MyStruct mystr READ getMyStruct
                WRITE setMyStruct NOTIFY myStructChanged)

public:
    explicit MyClass(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    MyStruct strObj;

     // Edit: changed get function
     MyStruct getMyStruct() const
     {
         return strObj;
     }

// Edit: Added set function
     void setMyStruct(myStruct val)
        {
            mystr = val;
            emit myStructChanged();
        }

signals:
void myStructChanged();

}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QObject>

#include "MyClass.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    MyClass classObj;

    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("classObj",&classObj);

    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

**Main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.3

ApplicationWindow {

    id: applicationWindow

    visible: true
    width: 600
    height: 400
    title: qsTr("My App")

    MainForm{
        id : mainform

        Component.onCompleted: {
        console.log("name===="+classObj.mystr.name1)

        //EDIT added more code to explain the use case.
        classObj.myStr.name1 = "abc"  //Calls setter 
        classObj.mystr.name2 = "ans" // Calls setter 
        }
    }
}
```

If i print just `(classObj.myVariant)` i am getting **QVariant(MyStruct)** but when i tried to access any parameter like `classObj.myVariant.name1` i am getting "**undefined**" and also how to set a variant from QML?

**[UPDATE]** - Should also add MyStruct to **Q_DECLARE_METATYPE** as below: **Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MyStruct)**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need meta data to access C++ objects from QML.

For non `QObject` derived, this is achieved by using the `Q_GADGET` macro, and exposing the members as properties:

```
struct MyStruct {
    Q_GADGET
    int m_val;
    QString m_name1;
    QString m_name2;
    QString m_name3;
    QString m_name4;
    Q_PROPERTY(int val MEMBER m_val)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString name1 MEMBER m_name1)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString name2 MEMBER m_name2)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString name3 MEMBER m_name3)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString name4 MEMBER m_name4)
};
```

Comment: It worked !!! if i need to fill a QVariant from QML.How to do that .Can you please give an example ?

Comment: @pra7 what do you mean by "fill"? Create or simply assign values to members?

Comment: Yes just assigning values to the members ,So that cpp can access the values set by QML.

Comment: Well, simply `yourvar.val = 555`.

Comment: Thanks ,I just changed **QVariant myVariant** inside **Q_PROPERTY**  to **MyStruct** and all return types to MyStruct. It worked.

Comment: Is there any way that i can set all the members of structures at once ? Now if i use **classObj.mystr.name1 = "abc"** ,**classObj.mystr.name2 = "ans"** and so on in QML ,Everytime setter is called. Is there any way to overcome this ? I have updated my question ,Please check.

Comment: No, there is no such thing possible. If it already works, you don't need to do anything additionally. If you want to save repetition, just write a function that sets everything that accepts target object and the 5 property values.

Comment: .Will try that .

Comment: Is there anyway to access structure inside a structure ? like `struct MyStruct {
    Q_GADGET
    int m_val;
    Mystruct1 str1; //NEW struct
   
    Q_PROPERTY(int val MEMBER m_val)
    Q_PROPERTY(int newStr MEMBER str1) //**ANYWAY to do this ?
};
`

Comment: Yes, if it is a property or a value returned from a `Q_INVOKABLE` function. Otherwise you can't get to it from QML.

Comment: I am getting error and I have posted as a new question please check : [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/q/45681872/6336374)

Comment: I don't think the implicit default constructor works the way you have wrote it. I am getting this error for a struct with one member variable: `candidate constructor (the implicit default constructor) not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 1 was provided`

Comment: @pooya13 I have no idea what you are doing, but it sounds like you as trying to use a constructor that doesn't exist. Double check your code.

Comment: @dtech I am trying to use your struct which has an implicitly defaulted constructor. This does not work as is since the Macros make that section private. I think you'd need to move the macros after the member variable declarations.

Comment: But I need to use `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE()` and `qRegisterMetaType<>()` to register it in order to avoid `unknown type` error.

Comment: I would suggest you expand on your answer to be a complete working example. I think the 10% left to the user is proving problematic

Answer (score 10):

1. your struct or simple class must have `Q_GADGET` as minimum
2. you should declare properties in order to access from qml
3. you must declare your struct/class by `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE()`
4. you must register it using `qRegisterMetaType<>()` somewhere before loading qml file by engine such as `main.cpp`

so you will have something like this:

```
//review carefully
struct MyStruct {
    Q_GADGET    //<-- 1.
    Q_PROPERTY(QString str1 MEMBER m_str1)    //<-- 2.
public:    //<-- important
    QString m_str1;
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MyStruct)    //<-- 3.
```

and use somewhere:

```
class Controller : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Controller(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    Q_INVOKABLE MyStruct setNewConfig(QString v);    //<-- e.g.
    //...
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
//...
qmlRegisterType<Controller>("AppKernel", 1, 0, "Controller");
qRegisterMetaType<MyStruct>();    //<-- 4.
//...
engine.load(url);
//...
```

so it is usable in qml
**main.qml**

```
//...
    Controller {
        id: con
    }
    FileDialog {
        id: fileDialog
        nameFilters: ["Config file (*)"]
        onAccepted: {
            var a = con.setNewConfig(file);
            console.log(a.str1);    //<-- yeah! it is here
        }
    }
//...
```

***NOTE 1:*** Be careful, it seems that nested classes/struct not supported by Qt meta

***NOTE 2:*** You can expose `struct` just like a `class`. Inherit from `QObject` and use `Q_OBJECT`. See [this article from Evgenij Legotskoj](https://evileg.com/en/post/305/)

***NOTE 3:*** Above instructions makes struct/class known to qml and you can access properties/members, but is not instantiable in qml. see [Qt document](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.12/qtqml-cppintegration-definetypes.html)

***NOTE 4:*** Be aware that `qmlRegisterType<>()` method is marked as "obsolete" in Qt 5.15+. Keep yourself updated ;)

Comment: This is a great description of how to use an *existing* struct, but what if the user simply wants to access the struct definition?

Comment: what do you mean @mzimmers? Maybe what you want, can be reached by full featured `QObject` based class instead.

Comment: I should have said the struct declaration, not definition (so one can create a new instance from QML). I think it may be possible by properly declaring the struct and invoking the c'tor with a QML var assignment, but I haven't figured it all out yet.

Comment: I already mentioned it in the **NOTE 3**. You need to declare a full featured `Object` based struct/class with `Q_OBJECT` macro in order to make it instantiable in QML. So, you can use that new type freely.