# Accessing Structure inside a structure in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qgadget

Previously I posted a question on how to access structures in QML and got perfect answers from some awesome people and now i need to know is there any way to access **structure inside a structure** in **QML**, Following is the code :

**//MyNewStruct**

```
struct MyNewStruct {
 Q_GADGET
    float m_range;
    Q_PROPERTY(float range MEMBER m_range)
};
```

**//MyStruct**

```
struct MyStruct {
Q_GADGET
int m_val;
QString m_name1;
QString m_name2;
QString m_name3;
QString m_name4;

MyNewStruct m_newStr; //**new Struct declaration

Q_PROPERTY(int val MEMBER m_val)
Q_PROPERTY(QString name1 MEMBER m_name1)
Q_PROPERTY(QString name2 MEMBER m_name2)
Q_PROPERTY(QString name3 MEMBER m_name3)
Q_PROPERTY(QString name4 MEMBER m_name4)

Q_PROPERTY(MyNewStruct newStr MEMBER m_newStr) //**Currently getting error as != cannot be used
};
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: `error: no match for 'operator!=' (operand types are 'myStruct1' and 'myStruct1')
             if (_t->mynewstr != *reinterpret_cast< myStruct1*>(_v)) {`
                              ^ **where Mystruct1 is myNewStruct**

Comment: I am no good at C++, but might I ask, why you are using `reinterpret_cast`? I thought there are almost no cases where this cast is necessary... But as I said, I am just learning C++ right now ;-)

Comment: @derM I suspect this is moc generated code.

Comment: Ok. :-( Nothing new to learn.

Comment: @derM this is moc generated error. I am just using the code as above .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error which I was getting in MOC was due to operator "**!=**" functionality was still undefined.

Since these kinds of structure definitions are required when we are building a **complex** application/module that's where I thought of posting this question here and also there is no proper doc  available.

Coming to the question: I used simple operator loading in my struct (since methods are allowed here ) Following is the code:

```
struct MyNewStruct {
 Q_GADGET
    float m_range;
    Q_PROPERTY(float range MEMBER m_range)

    //Overload operator !=
    bool operator!=(const MyNewStruct & val)
    {
         //Do check with local members and return true/false
    }
};
```

By doing this I was able to access MyNewStruct in QML.Hope it helps others.