# How to expose C++ struct to QML?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

My aim is to show angle and length values at ui. However I am not even able to reach that variable from qml  file and forward it to the console. I have implemented [this topic](https://forum.qt.io/topic/82325/best-way-to-access-a-cpp-structure-in-qml) but no hope. I need help!

controller.h

```
#ifndef CONTROLLER_H
#define CONTROLLER_H

#include <QObject>

struct MyStruct {
    float angle;
    uint16_t length;
};


class Controller : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:

     explicit Controller(QObject *parent = nullptr);
     MyStruct plate;

};

#endif // CONTROLLER_H
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <controller.h>
#include <QtQml>
#include <qquickview.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    Controller ctrl;
    QQmlContext *ctx=engine.rootContext();
    ctx->setContextProperty("controller", &ctrl);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Button{
        onClicked: {
            console.log(controller.plate.length)
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Actually I have tried that example and it did not work either :(

Answer (score 3):

Since your `Controller` class inherits from `QObject`, it should be accessible from QML. But the `MyStruct` type will not as is, be because it is not derived from `QObject`. For lightweight objects (which don't need signals/slots) you can use the `Q_GADGET` macro instead, which will provide the support required for participating in the runtime system and support reflection.

```
struct MyStruct {
    Q_GADGET
    public:
        float angle;
        uint16_t length;
};
```

This will enable you to access `MyStruct` members in QML. Though if you want to create new instances, you would need to make it derive from `Object` and register it with `qRegisterMetaType` as described in [How to create new instance of a Q_GADGET struct in QML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42797359/how-to-create-new-instance-of-a-q-gadget-struct-in-qml)

Comment: This is basically what I've linked to by voting to close this question...

Comment: @gavinb adding Q_GADGET makes all of my struct variables private. Any suggestion for that.

Comment: @BerkantAy Just add a `public:` line after the macro. I updated the answer.

Comment: you are my hero @gavinb

Comment: Actually i am not able to reach struct in my qml @gavinb